# Using graph theory to generate an exam schedule

Tags: matrix, graph-theory

I came across this website while looking for help on the internet regarding adj. matrix / graph theory.

**My program layout is as follows**:

- student name + courses stored in a 2D
- array array with all distinct courses

**I am trying to achieve the following**:

- use adjacency matrix to create an
  exam schedule where no student needs
  to write more than one exam a day

**Once the matrix is made, the results on the screen should be displayed as:**

- output a day by day exam schedule by course
- output the exam days of any student inquired

I am not really sure how to work on this. AFAIK, the best approach would be to create an overall exam schedule of all the distinct courses and computing it in such a way that no exams conflict with one another.

Any help/advice/links is greatly appreciated.

---

Any suggestions on how to program this? I can't seem to find any pseudo code or guidance on programming the graph coloring problem.

Comment: I merged the 2nd question into the top, losing a comment by Dairo: "Try a naive brute-force solution (recursion, backtracking) first. Afterwards, you can introduce heuristics."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can model your problem as a [graph coloring-problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_coloring#Scheduling).

Edit:
Another heuristic approach using [genetic algorithms](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/GaClassSchedule.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest taking the brute-force approach, to start. The number of possible arrangements of exams is likely small enough to exhaustively search them.

To give more detail for a solution, it would help to know more about the problem: How many exams per day? Is it possible for there to be multiple simultaneous exams, or are they all sequential?